# Pi refusing to connect to internet/IP 169.254.x.y is always appearing when connecting to my PC through ethernet

Tags: raspbian, networking, remote, dhcp

So as the title says, I've been trying to share the internet from my pc to my pi, running the pi headless and remotely connecting to it and whatsoever. However, whilst I can just do a remote connection to it just by using its hostname, it refuses to connect to the internet, always giving out the address **169.254.x.y** meaning that it could not find a DHCP server.

**My current config**
The PC has network sharing enabled, sharing to the ethernet port. The ethernet was given the static address of 192.168.137.1, with its subnet mask being the usual 255.255.255.0. It worked when I did it like 3 days ago, but it does not want to work now. Checked the cables for damage, switched them even but still no success. Restarted my pc to see if there'd be any change, but nothing happened.

Is there anything that can be done about this? I have tried to find a solution to this problem all over the web but it seems I'm only experiencing this specific issue.

Comment: This appears to be a variation on your previous questions. You don't provide any details so no one can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting the pi to your router without the pc in the way and see if it gets an IP address.   If it does then the problem is with your pc not responding to DHCP requests.